# NullPE on starting new Activity in Fragment using FragmentPagerAdapter with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a `viewpager` which is attached using an adapter which has 2 `Fragment`s attached to it. I am basically trying to implement Signin/Signup pages and am using fragments for this. Also, this is my first attempt at using fragments.

Now, from each of these two fragments I want to start another `Activity` on button click, which will launch an `AsyncTask`. This `AsyncTask` will make calls to signin or signup requests and after completion will store the data in a session_details (using sharedPreference). After making the session this will start an activity using Intent. Also, the Object used in the following code is a serializable object.

My Problem is that when I try to start Intent using `startActivityforIntent()` I get a `NullPointerException`. I am storing fa which is initialized using `getActivity()` and that prints the toast correctly but doesn't work for starting Intents. Am I missing out on something? Do I need to register any of the fragments inside manifest? I have registered only the RegLoginActivity in the manifest. Also, please note that I am writing the whole code in one file so am using inner class to implement Fragments.

```
public class RegLoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg_login);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    session_details = SessionManager.getInstance(RegLoginActivity.this.getApplicationContext());

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    TwoTabAdapter tabAdapter = new TwoTabAdapter(fm);

    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
}



private class TwoTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TwoTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        if (arg0 == 0) {
            return Login.loginInstance();
        } else if (arg0 == 1){
            return Register.registerInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}

public static class Login extends Fragment {

    private static Login login;
    private static FragmentActivity fa;

    public static Login loginInstance() {
        if (login == null) 
            login = new Login();
        return login;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fa = getActivity();
        View v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
        loginScreen = v.findViewById(R.id.login_screen);
        login_email_id = (EditText) loginScreen.findViewById(R.id.login_email_id);
        login_password = (EditText) loginScreen.findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        login_button = (TextViewBold) loginScreen.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new RegLoginActivity().new ClickHandler());
        return v;
    }
};

private class ClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == login_button.getId()) {
            userLogin();
        }
    }
}

private void userLogin() {

//This Toast is getting displayed on each click of Login.

    Toast.makeText(Login.fa, "starting Email Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    EmailLogin t = new EmailLogin();
    t.execute();
    try {
        t.get();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
    }

    if (user != null && user.id != 0) {
        session_details.createLoginSession();
                    try {


            Intent i = new Intent(Login.fa, OverviewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("user", user);
**//This Intent throws Null Pointer Exception
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);**
        } catch(Exception e) {
**//This says NullPointerException**
            android.util.Log.v("Intent Exception", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

The stack trace:

```
06-07 14:06:34.340: W/System.err(929): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 14:06:34.351: W/System.err(929):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
06-07 14:06:34.351: W/System.err(929):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
06-07 14:06:34.351: W/System.err(929):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
06-07 14:06:34.361: W/System.err(929):  at <packageName>.RegLoginActivity.userLogin(RegLoginActivity.java:343)
06-07 14:06:34.361: W/System.err(929):  at <packageName>.RegLoginActivity.access$8(RegLoginActivity.java:317)
06-07 14:06:34.361: W/System.err(929):  at <packageName>.RegLoginActivity$ClickHandler.onClick(RegLoginActivity.java:306)
06-07 14:06:34.371: W/System.err(929):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
06-07 14:06:34.371: W/System.err(929):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
06-07 14:06:34.371: W/System.err(929):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-07 14:06:34.381: W/System.err(929):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 14:06:34.381: W/System.err(929):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 14:06:34.381: W/System.err(929):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-07 14:06:34.381: W/System.err(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 14:06:34.391: W/System.err(929):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-07 14:06:34.391: W/System.err(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-07 14:06:34.391: W/System.err(929):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-07 14:06:34.401: W/System.err(929):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace

Comment: I have added the stacktrace

Comment: Which version of android framework do you use?

Comment: min API is 8 target is 19

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice in Android keeping references to either Fragments or Activities, as they might be destroyed by the system at any time. Rather than keeping a reference to an Activity within a Fragment, you should use the method getActivity() which might return null if the Fragment is not attached. You might want to enclose calls to getActivity() withing an if-statement on the condition isAdded() which tells you whether the Fragment is attached to an Activity or not.

Comment: The getActivity must be added where? when I tried adding it in the Intent, it was not visible

Comment: getActivity() should be used whenever you want to obtain a reference to the Activity containing the Fragment. It might be null if the Fragment is not attached. What do you mean by not visible? I'm referring to that static member you have in your fragment called 'fa'. That's wrong, first because it's static and secondly because you should never ever keep references to Activities as I tried to explain earlier.

Comment: okay, I understand that it is not a good practice, and that I should call the getActivity() method, but that still doesn't resolve why Toast is displayed every time but the Intent throws NullPointerException when they both use 'fa'